# Filtering who can connect to me via ssh

Tags: ssh, security, sshd

I want to access my home pc from my laptop. This will make working on projects while in university much easier (and a whole bunch of other things)

I've successfully installed ssh and ssh-server.
I managed to connect via ssh both via localhost and my internet ip.
I got warned that the host might be insecure, got my fingerprint and connected successfully (after I entered my user and password).

Despite having to know a user and a password to connect I don't find this too secure.

Is it secure (aka am I wrong) If I am not wrong what are common ways to ensure that only people I want can connect to me (some certificate or something ?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A secure way to connect to your computer through SSH is to use public key encryption, see [here for an example of how to set it up.](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html)

Public key encryption sets up a public/private key for you to use to connect to a server without having to enter a password each time you connect. It is more secure than just username/password, although a username/password combination is often used. [Here is more information on hardening an SSH server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server).

Comment: I've generated both keys in the set up link. Problem is I can log in without the key (I deleted it) just fine. Do I have to set something in a configuration file to turn on the key authentication ?

Comment: [See my second link](http://askubuntu.com/a/2279). Follow the instructions to disable password SSH access.